# IE9 Errors when using videoJS-vimeo plugin

Tags: javascript, video.js, vimeo-api

Hi I am using the VideoJS-Vimeo plugin which appears to work well on all browsers except IE9 (which is spoiling the party as usual) FF, Chrome, Edge, IE11, and 10 all work fine.

I receive the following 3 errors in the IE9 console:

> script5009 'Math' is undefined
>   206182609?api=1&player id=vjs video 1262 Vimeo api, line 1, character 13281
>
> script5009 'encodeURIComponent' is undefined
>   206182609?api=1&player id=vjs video 969 Vimeo api, line 1, character 10215
>
> script5009 'Object' is undefined
>   206182609?api=1&player id=vjs video 1262 Vimeo api, line 1, character 13281

These errors don't seem to appear in other browsers

My code and refs are below:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`

`<link href="bower_components/video.js/dist/video-js.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

`<script src="bower_components/video.js/dist/video.min.js"></script>`

`<script src="bower_components/videojs-vimeo/src/Vimeo.js"></script>`

```
<video
    id="xvid1"
    class="video-js vjs-big-play-centered clickableVideo"
    controls
    preload="none"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
    data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["vimeo"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/vimeo", "src": "https://vimeo.com/35982411"}], "vimeo": { "iv_load_policy": 1 } }'>
 </video>
```

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: All those three objects definitely exist in IE9

Comment: Im not sure, do you know how I would check that ?

Comment: why would you need to, Object and Math are as old as javascript - the error seems unlikely!! check what the code does in the specified position

Comment: It appears that Vimeo doesn't even work on IE9 as its no longer supported which may explain the errors. God knows what i'm going to do as a fall back...? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ouch, IE9 is important for all those windows 7 and 2008R2 users that have never installed a service pack ... or windows vista users ... both of them

Comment: Hilariously their website isn't even supported in IE9, it just stacks to the left hand side of the page.